# Custom Role Provider - DbContext disposed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, autofac

I have an MVC 3 application using Entity Framework in which I've setup a custom role provider.

My role provider depends on a repository and that repository has a dependency on a DbContext.

I'm registering both my context and repository in the app start method as implemented interfaces - instance per http request.

I initially tried using the Initialize method in my custom role provider to resolve the repository dependency using the service locator pattern and set it to a property of the class:

```
DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IMyRepository>();
```

The repository resolves without issue however, I get an exception stating the `DbContext` has been disposed.

I've been able to solve this by changing two things:

- Registering both the repository and context as instance per dependency rather than per http request.
- Resolving the repository dependency each time a method of the role provider is called by using a getter on a property rather than once in the initialize method.

So this all seems to work fine now however, I don't fully understand why even after reading various articles around autofac lifetime scopes.

*Code samples to come

My only theory is that the role provider kicks in before the http request is made therefore, when using instances per http request - the role provider is resolving instances for the previous request which have since been disposed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lifetime of Asp.Net role providers are managed by the runtime and are tied to the lifetime of the application not an individual request.

Hence if you resolve dependencies in the initialise method then this will only happen once leading to it hanging onto a disposed DbContext. Standard practice is to resolve once per method as per your fix.

With respect to the lifetime management of the DbContext that is used by the role provider, I would set the role provider up to use its own DbContext anyway (and hence unit of work) per atomic operation. Re-using the DbContext from elsewhere is potentially okay if your role provider is only doing reads. However, if it runs commands against your database you are at the mercy of the owner of the root scope of the DbContext to commit those changes.

I would imagine your explanation for why perHttpRequest fails is correct and just use per dependency as for the reason above.